# Does Chrome attempt to "unbundle" JavaScript sources into their original files for display in the debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, bundle

I am working a web application that has been coded by someone else.  Loading the index page, if I open the Chrome debugger and look at the Sources tab I see the following (notice the files highlighted in blue):

[image]

**I am trying to understand these blue highlighted files.**  They are not contained anywhere in my project, and I don't even have an E drive.  They don't appear to be downloaded in any requests on the Network tab either, even after a cache-clear.  The green highlighted files are present as expected in the Scripts folder and are referenced from my HTML.

Firefox / Firebug does not show any sign of these extra blue files.

If I open helix.container.js (the green one above), then for each of the blue files I see code like this, which is followed by the source code for that file:

```
function(require,module,exports){
/**
 * Helix.Ajax.js
 */
...
```

So it appears that helix.container.js is a bundled version of all the blue files. So therefore does Chrome somehow know this, and attempts to "unbundle" it back into its original files for display in the debugger?  If so, where is the path "e:\builds" coming from?  Can it be disabled?  Is there documentation?

Can anyone shed some light on this behavior?

This is using Chrome 30.0.1599.101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for source maps:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: This was it, thanks. The final line of helix.container.js contains the comment `//@ sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoiZ2....` with a huge base64 string of the entire source map.

Comment: No problem, I too was thrown off by this recently